# sequence comprehensions to get run

Tags: clojure

The below code I have found from a book (Functional Programming Patterns in Scala and Clojure). The for statement uses close-zip? to filter out people outside of the zips and then it generates a greeting to the people who are left. However, I am not quite sure how people should look like as argument for `generate-greetings` and `print-greetings` functions?

```
(def close-zip? #{19123 19103})

(defn generate-greetings [people]
  (for [{:keys [name address]} people :when (close-zip? (address :zip-code))]
    (str "Hello, " name ", and welcome to the Lambda Bar And Grille!")))

(defn print-greetings [people]
  (doseq [{:keys [name address]} people :when (close-zip? (address :zip-code))]
    (println (str "Hello, " name ", and welcome to the Lambda Bar And Grille!"))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They need to be maps with `:name` and `:address` keys, like:

```
{:name "A Person", :address {:zip-code 19103}}
```

`for` will take each element from `people` and assign each one to `{:keys [name address]}`. This is called [destructuring](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html), and it's just a convenience. It's the same as saying:

```
(for [person people
      :let [name (:name person)
            address (:address person)]
      :when (close-zip? (:zip-code address))]
  (str ...))
```